# Embedding UIViewController view inside another UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In my app, I have a *login-register-forgotpasword* wireframe. Each step of the process is implemented in a separate `UIViewController`, all of them inside the same `Storyboard`, and transitions between each controller are animated. So far so good.

Now we've changed the design, so all views have the same background elements and a header (not exactly a `UINavigationBar`), and I don't like the feel of the animation to a view that always looks to be actually the same, but just showing a different form. So I'm considering different approaches to, instead of pushing whole controllers, just showing/hiding its views, but staying in the same controller.-

**1)** My first try was instantiating the controller which view I want to show, and add it to the current view. Something like.-

```
- (IBAction)btnRegisterPressed:(id)sender {
    _viewHome.hidden = YES;    
    RegisterController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"registerNewUser"];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
}
```

This one would be perfect, as I'm using static `UITableViews` for my forms, so as far as I know I'd need a `UITableViewController` for each one. But it seems `IBOutlets` and `IBActions` got broken. **Is this approach possible in some way? If so, it's considered a bad practice?**

**2)** My second option is just creating all the views inside one controller, and properly showing/hiding them. This would one be hard to maintain, and chances are I'd have to forget about static `UITableViews`.

**Could anyone give me some advice of which option would be better, or point me to any other possible approach I'm missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option #1 is not appropriate as written but close to an approach you should probably consider. You can add nest the views of different `UIViewController`s however when you do so you should use the methods described in [Managing Child View Controllers in a Custom Container](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW86) so that the parent controller correctly manages its child controllers.

Comment: Thanks @Jonah, pretty interesting, didn't know of child view controllers at all. I guess I'll give them a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as many tableviews as you want for the same controller. The delegate methods contains the object that fired the method itself.

Following this approach (which i wouldn't recommend) you can probably tag your tableviews and then do:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
        doStuff;
    } else if (tableView.tag == 2) {
        doOtherStuff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Astri, is this true for static tables as well?

Comment: Yes, it will work in any case. Just set the delegate and the datasource of your tableview and then you can play with the delegate methods as i wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, personally, I feel we should keep things simple and straight forward for end user to quickly gel up with your app. Animations plays an important role in this. Tapping on cell of a tableview pushes another table view and there are different UI widgets like chevron that indicates the transition and user is not surprised.

Showing everything on single screen and hiding/unhiding them based on user's action is fine as long as you have proper animation. For instance, you might have seen TableView sections collapsing/expanding on tap.

You need to make a trade off and see what best suits based on your application. Whatever you decide my suggestion would be to add nice animations instead of simple hide/unhide.

Comment: Thanks @Abhinav. Actually I've planned to fade in/out my views. The static tables contain form fields in its cells, so I don't think it makes much sense to use the traditional left to right transition.