# How to show particular view in one screen to particular view of another screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Suppose I have 3 viewControllers "viewControllers A" "viewControllers B" "viewControllers C", and have some view in "viewControllers A" and "viewControllers B"  and I want to summarise that views in "viewControllers c" means I want to show that views in "viewControllers C"

I wants to do this because, I have 10 screens all have some graphs, and 11th screen is summary screen in which I wanted to show all that graphs

Comment: Note that one view can not have multiple superviews.

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the view and corresponding code into a new viewController. You can then add that new viewController as a child of your summary viewController. That way you get to reuse your code for filling the graph and still get the proper ViewController lifecycle.

Check this question/answer for more info on Child controller - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918476/embedding-uiviewcontroller-view-inside-another-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: thanks, but using this we can show whole view not particular view in any viewController, but I want to show particular view in "nibA"